# AWS EC2 cannot send and receive UDP packets more than 100 times

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sockets, udp

I wrote a java code to measure the speed of UDP.
I opened a UDP server on my home network, and AWS EC2 became a client.

I opened a port in my home network firewall.
AWS security groups allowed all traffic from all sources.

There is no problem when the packet size is 400B or 4KB.
(Excluding some loss that occurs due to the nature of UDP)

However, when the packet size becomes 40 KB, only the first 100 transmissions and receptions are possible, and all packets are lost thereafter. (I wrote the code for sending and receiving 1000 times at 10 ms intervals.)

Is there something wrong with my code?
Or does AWS block excessive UDP traffic?

UDPSender is a client that runs on AWS, and UDPSendBack is a server that runs on my home network.

```
import java.net.*;

public class UDPSender { //Send and receive

    private final DatagramSocket socket;

    private final String RECEVER_IP;
    private final int PORT;
    private final int SIZE;
    private final int REPEAT;

    private int COUNT = 0;
    private int WRONG_COUNT = 0;
    private int TIME_SUM = 0;

    private synchronized void COUNT() { COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void WRONG_COUNT() { WRONG_COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void TIME_SUM(int time) { TIME_SUM += time; }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"192.168.1.33", "53135", "40000", "1000"};

        new UDPSender(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
    }

    public UDPSender(String ip, int port, int size, int repeat) throws Exception {
        this.RECEVER_IP = ip;
        this.PORT = port;
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.REPEAT = repeat;

        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();

        for (int i = 1; i <= REPEAT; i++) {
            send(i);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void send(int id) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = createData();
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(RECEVER_IP);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, PORT);

                socket.send(packet);
                System.out.println(id + " messages sent");
        
                receive(socket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void receive(DatagramSocket socket) throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        socket.receive(packet);

        long sendTime = validateData(packet.getData());
        long taken = System.currentTimeMillis() - sendTime;
        COUNT();

        if (sendTime == -1) {
            WRONG_COUNT();

            return;
        }

        TIME_SUM((int)taken);

        System.out.println(COUNT + " messages received (including " + WRONG_COUNT + " wrong message) / Time taken " + taken + "ms (Average " + String.format("%.3f", (double)TIME_SUM / COUNT) + "ms)");
    }

    private byte[] createData() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                buffer[i + j] = (byte) (currentTime >> (56 - (8 * j)));
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }

    private long validateData(byte[] data) {
        long sendTime = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            long time = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                time |= ((long) data[i + j] & 0xff) << (56 - (8 * j));
            }

            if (sendTime != -1 && time != sendTime) {
                return -1;
            }

            sendTime = time;
        }

        return sendTime;
    }

}
```

```
import java.net.*;

class UDPSendBack { //Receive and send

    private final DatagramSocket socket;
    private final int SIZE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"53135", "40000"};

        new UDPSendBack(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }

    public UDPSendBack(int port, int size) throws Exception {
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
    
            new Thread(() -> {
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());

                try {
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
        
                    System.out.println("Received message and send back");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"when the packet size becomes 400 KB"* - the maximum size of a UDP packet is less than 64k.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So why are the first 100 packets delivered normally? I wonder

Comment: *"So why are the first 100 packets delivered normally?"* - I'm not sure what you are doing. But if I use your code and give a message size of 400000 (or even 66000) I get as expected `java.io.IOException: Message too long`. So you are likely doing something different when claiming to send 400KB.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Oh, I'm so sorry.
There was a mistake when writing the article.
400B and 4KB are delivered just fine, but at 40KB only the first 100 packets are sent.

Did it work normally when the message size was set to 400000 and the number of transmissions was set to 100 or more?

Comment: Also, thank you so much for trying to help me even get my code running.

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific case of AWS to home connectivity. But in general: the larger the datagram is, the more fragments when sending the datagram are needed. If only one of the fragments gets lost the whole datagram is lost. Then 40k vs. 4k means sending with 10x the bandwidth - which increases the likelihood of fragments gets lost. And there might also be bandwidth control involved by AWS or by your home ISP.